# Make URL case insensitive

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, case-insensitive

I'm trying to get the following URLs be case insensitive and to go to same spot:

```
http://www.example.com/ReVieW
```

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]

RewriteRule ^/review ${lc:$1} [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^/review /example/review-landing.html [PT,L]
```

Above rule should redirect it to `http://www.example.com/review`.

This rule is giving 404 error for any uppercase.

Comment: The code is in htaccess or server config?

Comment: i have a jb.config file with virtualhost entry, jb.config imports the file having this rule.